# $n^2+(n+1)^2+n^2\cdot(n+1)^2$ is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $n^2+(n+1)^2+n^2\cdot(n+1)^2$ is a perfect square, for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

I have not tried anything but numerical calculations.

Comment: You're supposed to indicate what you've tried, not what you haven't.

Comment: Why don't you try multiplying it all out, and seeing what it might be the square of?

Comment: $n^2+(n+1)^2+n^2\cdot(n+1)^2 = (n^2 + n + 1)^2$.

Comment: A little more interesting IMO: You can also prove that it is never a perfect power of $4$.